# Show two matrices are conjugate in $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations

Let $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ be the group of invertible two-by-two matrices over the complex numbers, with matrix multiplication the group operation.

**Question:** Show that $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is conjugate to $\begin{bmatrix}i & 0 \\ 0 & -i\end{bmatrix}$,

ie. there exists $A \in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}i & 0 \\ 0 & -i\end{bmatrix}$.

This might be silly, but I can't seem to figure out how to cause the 'change in orientation' when I am conjugating. I have tried conjugating with $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ i & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & i\end{bmatrix}$, and neither of these work.

Ideally, I'd like to know not just the solution, but why the solution works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the second given matrix is diagonal, so you can think of it as the result of diagonalizing the first one. So all you've got to do is use the standard procedure for diagonalizing the first matrix: you already know its eigenvalues (the common eigenvalues of both matrices are clearly seen in the second one), and you only need to find the corresponding eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just process the diagonalization algorithm.

Or another tedious method is to simply calculate 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
d & -c \\ -b & a
\end{bmatrix} = \mathrm {diag(\mathrm i, \mathrm -i)}
$$
where $ad-bc = 1$ then solve it for $a, b,c ,d \in \mathbb C$. It may not works [since you may get duplicated equations which means the restrictions would be loose and the solution is harder to find], but it is the direct way, and it works for other matrices.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for pointing it out, my bad.

Comment: @A.Goodier Oh, sorry. Thanks for pointing out. Now the answer is edited.